# Error al usar Template con Matrices de String en C++

Tags: c++, dev-c++, template-strings

Buenas a los que me puedan ayudar les agradecería, estoy haciendo este programa con plantillas donde la idea es pedir datos y luego mostrarlos en consola. Con el vector de INT y el de FLOAT el programa funciona sin problema pero con el vector de Strings el programa solo recibe 4 datos antes de cerrarse dándome el mensaje de `return value 3221225477` no se cual sea la solución o que estoy haciendo mal

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <fstream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;
using std::string;
/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */
template<class M, size_t N>
void leer(M [][N]);
template<class T, size_t N>
void mostrar(T [][N]); 

int main(int argc, char** argv) {
    int edad[3][2];
    string nombre[3][2];
    float precio[3][2];
    
    leer(edad);
    mostrar(edad);
    leer(nombre);
    mostrar(nombre);
    leer(precio);
    mostrar(precio);
    
    
    return 0;
}

//FUNCION LEER
template<class MATRIZ, size_t N>
void leer(MATRIZ a[][N]){
    cout<<"Digite los datos de la matriz: "<<endl;
    for(int i=1; i<=3; i++){
        for(int l=1; l<=2; l++){            
            cin>>a[i][l];
        }
    }
}

//FUNCION MOSTRAR
template<class MAT, size_t N>
void mostrar(MAT a[][N]){
    cout<<"------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Mostrando los datos de la matriz: "<<endl;
    for(int i=1; i<=3; i++){
        for(int l=1; l<=2; l++){
            cout<<a[i][l]<<endl;
        }
    }
    cout<<"------------------------------"<<endl;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Pasa que en C++ los índices **empiezan en 0**, no en 1.

Al usar los índices en el rango 1..3 en vez de 0..2 estás escribiendo fuera de la memoria de la matriz.

Si intentas leer o escribir un tipo nativo (`int`, `float`, ...) el programa no se romperá ya que en el caso de estos tipos se produce un acceso directo a memoria.

En el caso de `string`, el programa muere porque ahora estamos tratando con una clase que además gestiona memoria dinámica. Lo que sucede en este caso es que la posición de memoria que corresponde al puntero donde la clase `string` "guarda" la cadena está apuntando a una posición aleatoria de memoria. Como esa posición no te pertenece el Sistema Operativo mata el proceso para evitar que corrompa memoria de otras aplicaciones.

Corregido quedaría así:

```
//FUNCION LEER
template<class MATRIZ, size_t N>
void leer(MATRIZ a[][N]){
    cout<<"Digite los datos de la matriz: "<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(int l=0; l<2; l++){            
            cin>>a[i][l];
        }
    }
}

//FUNCION MOSTRAR
template<class MAT, size_t N>
void mostrar(MAT a[][N]){
    cout<<"------------------------------"<<endl;
    cout<<"Mostrando los datos de la matriz: "<<endl;
    for(int i=0; i<3; i++){
        for(int l=0; l<2; l++){
            cout<<a[i][l]<<endl;
        }
    }
    cout<<"------------------------------"<<endl;
}
```